# Google Vision API specify JSON file

Tags: c#, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm trying to authenticate to Google Vision API using a JSON file. Normally, I do it using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable which specifies the path to the JSON file itself.

However, I am required to specify this in my application itself and authenticate using the JSON file contents.

Now, I have tried to specify `CallSettings` to then pass it in as a parameter to the `ImageAnnotatorClient.Create` method. Sure enough, a `CallSettings` object can be created perfectly by reading the authentication info from the JSON file, but passing it in as a parameter to `ImageAnnotatorClient` seems to make no difference as the `ImageAnnotatorClient.Create` method is still looking for the environmental variable and throws an `InvalidOperation` exception, specifying that the environmental variable cannot be found.

Any idea how I can get the desired behavior?

[Google Vision Docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using Grpc.Auth;

namespace GoogleVision
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonPath = @"<path to .json credential file>";

            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath).CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);

            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);

            var image = Image.FromFile(@"<path to your image file>");

            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);

            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize that this is an old post, but I managed to figure it out, so I figured this might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonPath = "<YOUR PATH>";

var imageAnnotatorClientBuilder = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = jsonPath
};

var client = imageAnnotatorClientBuilder.Build();

IReadOnlyList<EntityAnnotation> textAnnotations = client.DetectText(image);
foreach (EntityAnnotation text in textAnnotations)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Description: {text.Description}");
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You should avoid code-only answers : could you add some explanation?