# No overload for method 'ImageAnnotatorClient.Create' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-client

I am using `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1, Version=2.0.0.0` and the following below code from [Google Vision API specify JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372938/google-vision-api-specify-json-file)

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using Grpc.Auth;
using Grpc.Core;

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("VisionProject.json");
        var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
```

But its shows me this error `No overload for method 'ImageAnnotatorClient.Create' takes 1 arguments`.

I have found similar code in documentation https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1P2Beta1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1P2Beta1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html

But for some reason, it's not working( unable to see the overload)

Comment: It seems you are looking at different version of API than you have installed. See [this](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#Google_Cloud_Vision_V1_ImageAnnotatorClient_Create)

Comment: so how can I adjust the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using newer version of API. [Docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/index.html#authentication) state that now authentication is set up(when needed) via environment variable:

> Otherwise, the simplest way of authenticating your API calls is to download a service account JSON file then set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to refer to it. The credentials will automatically be used to authenticate. See the [Getting Started With Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) guide for more details.

So you can do something like this:

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "PathTo_VisionProject.json");
 var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
```

Or set this environment variable some other way.

Answer (score 4):

While setting the environment variable is certainly *a* simple way of specifying which service account file to use, it's not the only one. You can use the builder to specify the path very easily:

```cs
var client = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = "VisionProject.json"
}.Build();
```

Comment: That's looking better. Thanks, Jon

Comment: @user960567: Nice to hear that - the general idea is to put as much as we can in the client builder pattern for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you do not have access to the JSON file directly and you want to stay close to what you previously did with the `GoogleCredential` and `Channel` creation is something like:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("VisionProject.json");
// or if you have access to the content only
// var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);
var client = await new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
{
    Endpoint = ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint, 
    ChannelCredentials = credential.ToChannelCredentials()
}.BuildAsync();
```